# ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError when reading config file Python

Tags: python, configparser

I am trying to read some values from a config file params.txt using ConfigParser in Python but keep getting a MissingSectionHeadError

I have a file params.txt:

```
[all]
zigzag = 0.08
fractal = 0.03
rng_length = 1000
stp = 100
```

and the following code:

```
parser = cp.SafeConfigParser()
g = open(params, 'r')
g.readline()
parser.readfp(g)
print parser.getfloat('all', zigzag)
```

where I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deadrabbit_console_0-1.py", line 166, in <module>
    DRconsole().cmdloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 221, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "deadrabbit_console_0-1.py", line 127, in do_load_data
    get_data(series, params)
  File "deadrabbit_console_0-1.py", line 115, in get_data
    parser.readfp(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 324, in readfp
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: /home/baconwichsand/Documents/Dead Rabbit/params.txt, line: 1
'zigzag = 0.08\n'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you are doing:

```
g.readline()
```

before passing the file to `readfp`. This will read the line containing `[all]` so when `SafeConfigParser` reads the file it will *not* read the section header, and you receive that error. To fix it simply don't call `readline()`:

```
In [4]: parser = cp.SafeConfigParser()
   ...: with open('data.ini', 'r') as g:
   ...:     parser.readfp(g)
   ...: print(parser.getfloat('all', 'zigzag'))
0.08
```